# Three-way pivot table or complex relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, relationship

I have two tables, shipments and customers. In the real world, a customer can be related to a shipment in three ways: as the biller, the destination and/or the origin.

So my question here is, do I have a pivot table with three columns, one for the shipment_id, one for the customer_id, and one for the relationship_type id? Or do I have separate tables? I'm not sure how best to approach this as it's the first of it's kind that I've run up against.

Comment: can a customer log in into your app ?

Comment: @lewis4u, yes that is one of the final intended purposes.

Comment: Well then that is your first mistake... anyone who can log in into your app should be in users table. and then you make roles table and assign roles to users, that is the best practice. A user can have many shipments and each shipment belongs to only one user. That should be your first relationship. Another relationship is obviously: A user can have many roles and each role belongs to many users. This one would be made with a pivot table.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I misunderstood your question. A user is related to the customer (as in a customer account, whether that be a personal or commercial or other type), a customer account can have multiple users associated with it. My position where I am getting stuck is about how to define the three relationships a customer account can have with a shipment (as in, is the customer the destination, origin and/or biller), and whether or not this would be a three columned pivot table (where the columns are shipment_id, customer_id, and type_id, or if I somehow need to make 3 different tables for such.

Comment: A customer account has many shipments and a Shipment belongs to only one customer account. Is this true or false? BTW why do you have a customer account model...that should be a User model from users table...We need to live chat, so I can understand you better

Comment: Alright, I'm out of the office at the moment but will be back in a few. As for the current thought process, a customer can have multiple users and multiple shipments. A shipment can technically belong to three (because of the origin, destination and biller portion I'm stuck at) and a customer account isn't referring to a user account at all, it is merely referring to the business accounts we have open physically in our office, it's not meant to act like a user account, it's to hold the primary information (such as billing and shipping information).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced this couple weeks ago and I came up with a solution.

> Assuming that one customer can have different relations to different
>   shipments.

First of all you need a new model for customer roles obviously that model it will be Relation model.

**First approach:** You could solve this by using more than one pivot table which works but its not a good database design. I solved it first like this but realized its not optimal choice when it comes to db.

**Second approach:** You could solve this by defining pivot table as a model, but I havent tried that way even though I know it works and its a solution.

**Better approach:** use one pivot table for three models. In that case you have to define pivot table when you define a relationship example :

Customer model:

```
public function relations()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Relation::class, 'customer_relation_shippment');
}
```

Relation model:

```
public function customers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Relation::class, 'customer_relation_shippment');
}
```

and the other model as well.

now lets say you want to add a relation to a customer.
Lets grab first customer and first shipment and say we want to add a relation as a biller:

```
$customer = Customer::first();

$shipment = Shipment::first();

$relation = Relation::where('name','biller')->get();

$customer->relations()->attach($shipment->id, ['relationship_type'=>$relation->id]);
```

By using only one pivot table of course its a bit more complex to perform operations towards those models like CRUD, but when it comes to database design/optimazation of course it is the right choice! Note that I came to this conclusion after dealing with a similar real world issue and it turned way more faster db interaction then using more than one pivot.

Comment: can your customers log in into your app with a username and password?

Comment: my case its slightly more advanced than this, but yes I have a master admin which defines user roles and random users that are defined by master admin they can login and check their shipment progress.

Comment: I just have a feeling that the OP is complicating things. The well known best practice is that anyone who can log is automatically a user and belongs into users table and then that user can have some roles. A customer, buyer, seller, admin, manager or any other... and then that user can have shipments or whatever. There is no need for Customer model and Relation model...that is breaking the rules.... A customer is a user of the app and Relation exists between models and it's declared between them

Comment: It depends what is the purpose of the app actually! And when it comes to role definition don't you think that is not very good a random user to decide the role for himself? That's why in my system it is maintained by a master admin with the power of changing user settings/roles. A random user in my app its a random user meaning can only get data reports and such nothing like changing roles or changing other data on the app.

Comment: Yes. That is the way to go. When a user registers he is nothing. An Admin  should first assign a role to him and activate him and then he can access things which are created for that role. But you @LeoKelmendi have Customer and Relation model which are unnecessary

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I would design your project.

I don't think you even need a pivot table or many-to-many relationship.

Note:  For clarity and avoiding confusion with the `User`, I will use `Account` to refer to what you call a `Customer`. At the end you used `customer account` in your comments.

You have a shipment that relates to three different *entities*. However, those entities are represented by the same data model in your database: the `Account` model.

A basic one-to-many relationship will suffice.

An account can have many shipments. And the shipment belongs to *one* account.

Now, how to add the "Type" of the relationship? We don't need a pivot table, we just add another one-to-many relationship.

- An `Account as biller` may have many shipments, and the shipment belongs to one `biller`.
- An `Account as origin` may have many shipments, and the shipment belongs to one `origin`.
- An `Account as destination` may have many shipments, and the shipment belongs to one `origin`.

**To explain, here is an example code:**

We have three models: `User`, `Account`, and `Shipment`

Let's start with the schema:

```
    Schema::create('accounts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('shipments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('from');
        $table->string('to');

        $table->unsignedInteger('biller_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('origin_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('destination_id');

        $table->foreign('biller_id')
            ->references('id')->on('accounts');

        $table->foreign('origin_id')
            ->references('id')->on('accounts');

        $table->foreign('destination_id')
            ->references('id')->on('accounts');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

We have three columns referencing the `id` on the `accounts` table.

For the models and the relationships:

**Account Model:**

```
class Account extends Model
{
    public function billerShipments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Shipment::class, 'biller_id');
    }

    public function originShipments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Shipment::class, 'origin_id');
    }

    public function destinationShipments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Shipment::class, 'destination_id');
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }

}
```

**Shipment Model:**

```
class Shipment extends Model
{
    public function billerAccount()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Account::class, 'biller_id');
    }

    public function originAccount()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Account::class, 'origin_id');
    }

    public function destinationAccount()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Account::class, 'destination_id');
    }

}
```

**Example to create a shipment**

```
    $billerAccount = \App\Account::create(['name' => 'account b']);
    $originAccount = \App\Account::create(['name' => 'account a']);
    $destinationAccount = \App\Account::create(['name' => 'account c']);

    $newShipment = \App\Shipment::create([
        'from'           => 'city 1',
        'to'             => 'city 2',
        'biller_id'      => $billerAccount->id,
        'origin_id'      => $originAccount->id,
        'destination_id' => $destinationAccount->id,
    ]);

    echo $billerAccount->billerShipments()->count(); // 1
    echo $originAccount->originShipments()->count(); // 1
    echo $destinationAccount->destinationShipments()->count(); // 1

    echo $newShipment->billerAccount->name === $billerAccount->name; // 1
    echo $newShipment->originAccount->name === $originAccount->name; // 1
    echo $newShipment->destinationAccount->name === $destinationAccount->name; // 1
```

For the account-user relationships, it can be many-to-many or one-to-many depending on your requirements.